# Printing a java map Map<String, Object> - How?

Tags: java, hashmap

How to I print information from a map that has the object as the value?

I have created the following map:

```
Map<String, Object> objectSet = new HashMap<>();
```

The object has its own class with its own instance variables

I have already populated the above map with data.

I have created a `printMap` method, but I can only seem to print the Keys of the map

How to do I get the map to print the `<Object>` values using a for each loop?

So far, I've got:

```
for (String keys : objectSet.keySet())
{
   System.out.println(keys);
}
```

The above prints out the keys. I want to be able to print out the object variables too.

Comment: Does `Map` only have a `keySet` method? Does it have no other methods?

Comment: Did you just try `println(map)`?

Comment: Also, 'keys' is not a good variable name for what is actually one key.

Answer (score 141):

I'm sure there's some nice library that does this sort of thing already for you...  But to just stick with the approach you're already going with, `Map#entrySet` gives you a combined `Object` with the `key` *and* the `value`.  So something like:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + entry.getValue().toString());
}
```

will do what you're after.

---

If you're using java 8, there's also the new streaming approach.

```
map.forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + ":" + value));
```

Comment: linked the lambda function from J8

Comment: This answer should have been accepted.  Poor SO etiquette!  Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 11):

You may use `Map.entrySet()` method:

```
for (Map.Entry entry : objectSet.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println("key: " + entry.getKey() + "; value: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There is a [get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object))  method in HashMap:

```
for (String keys : objectSet.keySet())  
{
   System.out.println(keys + ":"+ objectSet.get(keys));
}
```